# JSON values to Java class conversion

Tags: java, json, rest, spring-rest

I have a requirement where I have to create java classes for probable JSON response. So basically if I have,

```
{ email: 'email', password: 'pass' }
```

I should create a java class like below,

```
class Credentials
{
    string email;
    string password;

    // getter / setters below...
}
```

...and then mapping can be done later. That's how it works generally.

What I want is do we have any utility that can automatically create java classes from the JSON response? So if I pass the JSON object data like,

```
{ email: 'email', password: 'pass' }
```

I should get a java file automatically created like above. Why I am asking this is because the JSON that I have is pretty complex, objects inside objects inside objects. So I wanted to see if my coding can be reduced by some time if I can get the java file generated directly.

Please let me know if there is anything like this available?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -3):

Use this if you're using Jackson : https://github.com/astav/JsonToJava